# Micrsoft exchange

Tags: ipad, iphone, exchange-activesync

I have exchange email on my iPhone 6 Plus and a iPad.  My emails are still coming in but when I delete a email on my computer or move a email into a subfolder in my inbox it does not take effect on my iPhone and iPad.

Comment: If I delete the emails off my phone they will delete off my computer but not vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have configured the email account as Exchange or IMAP account on all devices.